# repeat an image from a specfic position to another specific position

Tags: html, css, image

i want to set an image in the background of a div with a property to repeat that image from  the start of the div to the 99% of height of the div.

Is this possible? OR i have to find another work round?

Answer (score 2):

Not purely with CSS background-repeat.  Once you specify a repeat in a direction (x or y), you get 100% of that element's width or height;

You could try adding an element that overlays 1% of your `<div>`s height, thereby hiding the background image.

Another option would be to nest 2 div's, and add the background-image to the nested element:

```
<div style="height: 100%">
    <div style="height: 99%; background: url(img.png) repeat-y 0 0;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this css:

```
.myimg {
    background-image:url(path here) repeat left top;
    height:99%;
}
```

You need to apply the class `myimg` to the image. You might want to adjust the height there.

Note that you can also customize the starting/repeating position of the image by specifying the values to left and top like:

```
background-image:url(path here) repeat 20% 50%;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with only CSS, you'll need an HTML `<div>` or similar to position the background.